# How do I make it so if the player wants they can hold the animation but if they don't hold it, it completes.. (physics based)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

so here is the scenario,
i want the player to be able to perform a trick, and then be able to hold the trick for a longer duration if they want to, but if they don't hold the input then they instead just continue the animation until completion as i haven't actually tried implementing too much and its not giving me the desired result i figured i'd just ask if people have already done it so i don't spend the next 2 hours down a rabbit hole, any and all help is appreciated thanks! :D

(Unity Script)

{

```
 [Header("Trick Attributes")]
 public string GroundTagName;        // Tag used for all the platforms
 public KeyCode stuntKey;
 public float AnimationFreezeTime = 0.75f;
 public SpriteAnimator anim;     // Put the Sprite animator here
 public Animator spriteAnimator;  // Put the Animator here
 private bool isGrounded;
 public bool stunting = false;

 private void Start()
 {
     
 }

 private void Update()
 {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(stuntKey) && !isGrounded)
     {
         anim.StartAnimation("FlyingSquirrel");
         stunting = true;
         Invoke("FreezeAnimation", AnimationFreezeTime);
     }
     if (Input.GetKeyUp(stuntKey))
     {
         stunting = false;
         spriteAnimator.speed = 1;
     }
 }

 void FreezeAnimation() {
     spriteAnimator.speed = 0;

 }

 private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
 {
     if (collision.gameObject.tag == GroundTagName)
     {
         isGrounded = true;

     }
     else
     {
         isGrounded = false;
     }

     if (stunting && collision.gameObject.tag == GroundTagName)
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
 }

 private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
 {
         isGrounded = false;
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FlyingSquirrel** needs to be broken up into 3 different animations. This can be done in Maya, Blender, uMotion, or even Unity's animation importer:
[image]

You need 3 Animator states:

- Start_FlyingSquirrel // Player moves into position
- Idle_FlyingSquirrel // Player is "holding" the trick
- End_FlyingSquirrel  // Player let go, return to normal

When the player presses button to start the trick, play the Start animation. For the transition, use "has exit time" to proceed to the Idle State. The Idle state will be true (use a boolean Animator parameter) while the trick is "held". Uncheck "has exit time" for the transition to the End state- you want this to happen instantly.

[image]

Comment: Also add a transition from Start to End, so if the player presses and lets go quickly, the idle state can be skipped completely.